# Grouping by month from a date with nested aggregations | SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a seemingly strange grouping error in `Teradata`. The query is calculating daily payment balance, and finding the smallest payment of each month, then aggregating by months. The issue arises when Im trying to group by months so I dont have duplicates like so:

| Customer | Currency | Date_Period | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 204,117,901 | EUR | 30/09/2021 | 0.06 |
| 204,117,901 | EUR | 30/09/2021 | 0.06 |
| 204,117,901 | EUR | 30/11/2021 | 1.07 |
| 204,117,901 | EUR | 30/11/2021 | 1.07 |

Instead, Im trying to get this:

| Customer | Currency | Date_Period | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 204,117,901 | EUR | 30/09/2021 | 0.06 |
| 204,117,901 | EUR | 30/06/2021 | 0.76 |
| 204,117,901 | EUR | 30/11/2021 | 1.07 |
| 204,117,901 | EUR | 31/01/2022 | 2.25 |

However, if i dont create a CTE or inline view, the `group by` causes 2 types of errors, either its nested aggregations not allowed in group by, or not all non-aggregated columns are present in group by (even though seemingly i select everything outside min() function). What would be the best way to do this? Code snippet without the group_by clause below.

```
select 
table1.Customer_Id  
, table1.Currency
, table1.Date_Period --end-of-month dates e.g. '30/11/2021' date type
-- , table1.Summary_Date --just for example what was used in partition clause, this is an every-day date e.g. '4/11/2021'
, min((case 
when table1.Criterion1 = supporttable1.Criterion1 
then cast((table2.Balance_Amount - table2.Reserved_Balance_Amount)as float)* cast(table3.Currency_Rate as float) 
else cast(table2.Balance_Amount as float) * cast(table3.Currency_Rate as float) end )) --over (partition by table1.Customer_id, extract(month from table2.Summary_Date) order by extract (month from table2.Summary_Date) asc) 
--does the job but does not remove duplicate rows
FROM table3 
inner join (( table1 full join supporttable1 on table1.Criterion1 = supporttable1.Criterion1
) 
inner join table2 on table1.customer_id = table2.customer_id 
) 
on table1.date_period = table3.date_period
-- GROUP BY table1.Customer_ID,   table1.Currency, table1.Date_Period) --gives back only minimum value of all period, where i need minimum of each month
```

Comment: that is all garbled up with a lot of errors, first fix the From clause, before starting the case when and window function  if you add all table with data here https://dbfiddle.uk/oDFlc0OJ  some one will be nice enough to fix it

Comment: Add back the `group by`. Strip out the `over` clause on your `min` function. Btw `extract(month)` will break once your data spans more than a year anyway.

Comment: @shawnt00 if i strip out the over clause on my min function and add back GROUP BY table1.Customer_ID,   table1.Currency, table1.Date_Period, then all i get is minimum values over all period, not minimum values per month

Comment: Isn't that what `Date_Period` is? You mention different date columns though.

Comment: the min() function intended to take each days value and find the minimum value for each month, and then final select should only display one minimum value per month, per customer